# Unable to read cell value from excel sheet using HSSF workbook in Java

Tags: apache-poi, poi-hssf, hssf

I have an excel sheet with following dummy data

```
UID     ROLL NO.    NAME
16004   1          fgh
16005   2          fhg
16006   3          dfg
16018   4          dfgdf
16029   5          sd
```

I have written a code that reads the data from excel and inserts that into database. While reading, I am able to read only the first column. I am getting null while reading the values of other columns.

Here is the code.

```
cell = row.getCell(0);
System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());//I am able to print this

cell = row.getCell(1);
System.out.println(cell);// here i am getting null
System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());// NUll pointer exception
                                              // Even get numeric value 
                                  //doesn't work as the cell itself is null.

cell = row.getCell(2); 
System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());//Here also I am getting Null 
                    //pointer exception (if the previous code is commented)
```

Can some one help me out?

Comment: what does it give as row.getLastCellNum()?

Comment: It is returning 1.

Comment: Found the problem. The problem is not with this code. It is with another snippet of code for which I found the solution.

Comment: So since 1 is  the last logical cell in the row PLUS ONE, there really is only a cell 0 in the row. It would seem you are going to need to give readers more to go on about how the row is set up. Oh, I see you found that. hurrah